# Dynamically assign alias to all the field names in msyql query

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, schema, alias

I have 2 tables in mysll DB. Both tables have few fixed and few dynamic columns (Fields / Schema). I want to join both these tables with following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `cd` cd
LEFT JOIN cd_n cn ON cd.id = cn.fk_cd
```

And I want to result as

```
CD_Column1   CD_Column1   CD_Column3   ...... CN_Column1   CN_Column2   CN_Column3  .....
value        value        value        ...... value        value        value       ...       
value        value        value        ...... value        value        value       ...
```

Where ..... is dynamic column names of both the tables. 
So the case is I dont know the column names because they are dynamic and I want rename (alias) it on query level. Please let me know how can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to do it on the database side? You can examine which table a result column comes from on your application side.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to query the `information_schema` to get the column names of that two tables. Lets assume You would have the `cd` column names stored in the array `$cd_columns` and the `cd_n` column names in the array `$cdn_columns`.

Then in PHP when creating the query loop through the column arrays and do something like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT ';

// add the cd columns
$i = 0;
foreach($cd_columns as $col) {
    $sql .= "{$col} AS CD_Column{$i},";
    $i++;
}

// add the cd_n columns
$i = 0;
foreach($cdn_columns as $col) {
    $sql .= "{$col} AS CN_Column{$i},";
    $i++;
}

// remove the trailing comma
$sql = trim($sql, ',');
// continue the SQL
$sql .= ' FROM ...';
```

Was this helpful?